# How to remake timezone with the regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, timezone, preg-replace

In my project I find timezones by id.

Here is an example:

```
(GMT+07:00) Indian, Christmas
```

How can I make it look like this:

```
Indian\Christmas
```

with regular expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single `preg_replace()` call will do the job.  My pattern and replacement will match the whole string and replace it with the first and second capture groups which will be joined together by `\`.

Code: ([PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bab11cc3a370775a39aa130123cf0948f6727f24))

```
$input='(GMT+07:00) Indian, Christmas';
echo preg_replace('/\S+ ([^,]+), (.+)/','$1\\\$2','(GMT+07:00) Indian, Christmas');
// output: Indian\Christmas
```

Here is the [Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vYt9WR/2)

---

This can be done several ways.  If you'd entertain a non-regex method, here is one that leverages the static length at the front of each string:

```
echo str_replace(', ','\\',substr($input,12));  // same output
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this : 1) Replace the Date between `()` with empty string `""`, 2) Replace the `,` with `\`

```
$string = '(GMT+07:00) Indian, Christmas';
$string = preg_replace("/\([^)]+\)/","",$string);// 'Indian, Christmas'
$string = preg_replace("/\, +\)/","\\",$string);// 'Indian\Christmas'
```